# How can I access to the SharedPreferences inside doInBackground AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem when I want to access to my **SharedPreferences** inside `doInBackground`. How can I do this?

Really thanks!

```
private class postData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    // I need to access here to my SharedPreferences //

  }
}
```

Comment: You can access SharedPreferences in background threads (the same way you do on a main thread) as they are stored persistently.

Comment: Thank you really much, it works! :D I don't know why i tought that I was unable of do that, I'll post my final code.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was easier than I thought.

```
private class postData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext() );    
    String userName = sharedPrefs.getString("auth_username", "");
    String userPass = sharedPrefs.getString("auth_password", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: IDK why would this work, the getApplicationContext() is a method of the Context class and the AsyncTask does not extend it

Comment: This answer is not correct, getApplicationContext() does not work here.

Comment: Check the link, This is work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855332/update-shared-preferences-from-asynctask-onpostexecute

Comment: The context bit is wrong, but you can pull some working bits out of this