# update shared preferences from AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

AsyncTask onPostExecute crashes (reports nullpointerexecption) when I try to use the value I received from doInBackground to update SharedPreferences.

My handle to the calling activity is: `private DashboardActivity<?> callerActivity;` with out the `<?>` it complains.  I've trie a couple of ways: 1) update SP in onPostExecute as:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(callerActivity);
prefs.edit().putInt("lastrecord", intRec ).commit();
```

I've also called a method in the callerActivity as:

```
callerActivity.storeLastInsertedRecord(intRec);
```

All the errors are the same, nullpointerexection on these lines.

What might I be doing wrong?  This answer [Android - shared preferences set in an AsyncTask onPostExecute() not always set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604414/android-shared-preferences-set-in-an-asynctask-onpostexecute-not-always-set) by @denisdrew is the closest, but for it crashes at the same place when I try instantiate the intent:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(callerActivity.getApplicationContext(), SharedPrefsHelperActivity.class);
```

or

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(callerActivity.getBaseContext(), SharedPrefsHelperActivity.class);
```

what might I be doing wrong?  I know that the value that I'm trying to push is not null (intRec).

Comment: Why is DashboardActivity generic?

Comment: Partly because I don't know what I'm doing, and of the options suggested by Eclipse, I took that generic.  Other AsyncTask classes that interact with my mysql over json don't complain when I leave it as `DashboardActivity callerActivity;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem is most likely related to Context that is assigned to **`NULL`**. I suggest you pass Context variable via constructor of AsyncTask e.q

```
private Context c;

public MyTask(Context c) {
   this.c = c;
}
```

And call it like:

```
new MyTask(YourCallerActivity.this).execute();
```

**Note:** I recently worked on similar issue(saving SharedPreferences in onPostExecute) and everything worked fine since i passed Context via constructor.

Comment: Technically this suggestion works.  Strictly speaking in this case it turns out that b/c callerActivity is actually of the form DashboardActivity<spectrum>, where spectrum refers to Surface view defined in the layout.xml. If I use the suggestion above, one of the things I'm trying to do is write to a remote db using my asynctask, so while it works, the data I write to the db does not get Inserted.

Comment: So I had to abandon the suggestion for that reason.  Elsewhere during a diff call to the remote server (in a diff. asynctask) I make fetch of the data that I want saved the shared preferences, and that works just fine b/c the callerActivity in this case is not of the ClassActivity<?>.